# \csname silences errors

Tags: csname

It seems that `\csname` automatically defines the control sequence in question if it's not already defined. The code below creates a document creating "a b c"; swapping the `\csname` line and `\foo` line gives an error. I would have expected `\csname` to simply give an error if used with an undefined control sequence, but instead it appears it defines the sequence to something empty?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
a
\csname foo\endcsname
b
\foo
c
\end{document}
```

It behaves exactly the same in pdflatex and lualatex, and with some syntactic differences the same behavior happens in pdftex and luatex as well. Is this expected behavior (and if so, where is it documented), and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the working of `\csname` is different from what you believe.

If the control sequence `\foo` is defined, then `\csname foo\endcsname` will be equivalent to `\foo`.

Otherwise, `\csname foo\endcsname` would (locally) define `\foo` as being equivalent to `\relax` and process it as such.

The relevant quotation from “TeX by Topic” (page 131):

[image]

You can do

```
\ifcsname foo\endcsname\csname foo\endcsname\else\ERROR\fi
```

to obtain the behavior you want.

Comment: ...where `\ERROR` is just a(ny) control sequence that does not exist.

Comment: That's kinda inconvenient. I wonder why it's defined like that.

Comment: @Caagr98 Knuth had good reasons for doing it and it's actually useful. You don't want a bunch of errors when you use `\csname` for a system of cross-references and the reference is not yet defined.

Comment: I suppose the intended use case is different from what I'm using it for. I still think the no-error version should be the one requiring `\ifcsname`, but I suppose there's no point arguing about it.